# How to add an ArrayField to a SearchVector in Django?

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql, search

I'm trying to use an ArrayField in a SearchVector but it is returning

```
django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal: ""
LINE 1: ... = to_tsvector(COALESCE("example_model"."example_arrayfield", ''))
                                                                      ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

When I query for the ArrayField it returns a list e.g. ["a","b","c"] whereas in the database it is shown in curley brackets instead e.g.{a,b,c}
Does anyone know how to get the SearchVector to accept an ArrayField as just a plain list? OR somehow convert the normal list to curley brackets?

Here is the code that starts this:

```
ExampleModel.objects.update(search_document=SearchVector("example_ArrayField"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's been a year, but I stumbled on this question via Google and could not find anybody with an acceptable solution for this exact problem, so here's the code I'm using.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchVectorField


class SearchableStuff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _('Name'),
        max_length=256,
        null=False, blank=False)
    tags = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True),
        verbose_name=_('Tags'),
        default=list,
        size=16,
        blank=True)
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(
        _('Search vector'),
        null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_vector = \
            SearchVector('name', weight='A', config='french') + \
            SearchVector(
                Func(F('tags'), Value(' '), function='array_to_string'),
                weight='A',
                config='french')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

--Edit-- a few hours after posting this solution, I realized that it does only work when updating a record, but not inserting it. Here's a better solution.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Note: we use `SearchVector(Value(self.field))` instead of
    # `SearchVector('field')` because the latter only works for updates,
    # not when inserting new records.
    self.search_vector = \
        SearchVector(Value(self.name), weight='A', config='french') + \
        SearchVector(
            Value(' '.join(self.tags)),
            weight='A',
            config='french')
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I ended up doing with this particular piece of code, but if you've managed to solve it then great, thanks for the update.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, exactly. The issue was that the search vector had to match exactly, so partial searches would fail to match. Instead I used a TrigramSimilarity to provide rank for partial matches. I also used a migration to add a postgres trigger to add the search vectors, instead of overriding save (which comes with the caveat described above. Example: http://logan.tw/posts/2017/12/30/full-text-search-with-django-and-postgresql/