# Can't save new objects in Django full-text search with PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm following [this](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/full-text-search-with-django-and-postgres/) post on how to add full-text functionality to my Django app. I have the following model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    alternative_names = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 250),blank=True,null=True)
    name_norm = models.CharField(max_length = 250,blank=True,null = True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250,unique = True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'imgs/users/%Y/%m/%d',blank = True)

    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_vector = (SearchVector('name', weight='A') )
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)`enter code here`
```

And when I try to save a new author with save:

```
    autor = Author(user = utilizador,name = author_name,alternative_names = alternative_names,name_norm = name_norm,slug = slug)
    autor.save()
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_v2.py", line 140, in <module>
    autor.save()
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/webapp/colunadeopiniao/accounts/models.py", line 57, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 748, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 785, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 890, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 927, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1393, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1336, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1337, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1337, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/mwon/NewArquivoOpiniao/env3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1263, in prepare_value
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to insert expression "SearchVector(Col(accounts_author, accounts.Author.name), weight=A)" on accounts.Author.search_vector. F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.
```

Django version: 3.0.11

Comment: There is decent (?) solution in the edit of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187585/499768

Answer (score 0):

> F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.

I'm no expert on VectorField, but maybe the `weight='A'` is causing the `F()` expression. Does it work without `weight`, as shown in the tutorial you refer to?

Otherwise, try an update:

```
Author.objects.all().update(search_vector=SearchVector('name', weight='A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you are trying to insert a value into the `search_vector` field when creating a new object of `Author`, but the `SearchVector` class only supports updating existing objects, not creating new ones. To solve this, you can change the implementation of the `save` method to update the `search_vector` field after the object has been created:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    Author.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(search_vector=SearchVector('name', weight='A'))
```

This way, you can create the object first, and then update the vector.

Answer (score 0):

the error is saying that  F() expressions can only be used to update
so you must use it after the object is saved
like on a post_save signal like this you are sure to call it after the object is saved

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def compute_search_vector_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.search_vector = (SearchVector('name', weight='A') )
```